# loading external XML file for parsing

Tags: xml, ajax, xml-parsing, external

```
setTimeout("newAJAXCommand('http://powercont.dyndns.org:1011/status.xml', updateStatus, true)",1000);
```

this doesn't seem to do anything, is there a way of making this work by pulling the xml file from a different server from where the script is running.

i've seen theres a way of loading an external xml file into a local xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't request another domain's page via JavaScript.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy